# using Ubuntu Desktop OS as always on SSH server

Tags: server, ssh, 20.04

I am trying to use a `Ubuntu Desktop` (on a laptop) as an `SSH server` that should **always be on** and accessible over the local WiFi network. However, I am facing a series of seemingly unending issues.

1. I was able to ssh to the machine with the `IP address` but not by machine name. I followed a solution on google to install `samba` and it worked.
2. It used to disconnect whenever I close my laptop lid. I had to then google all over the internet to find and patch relevant settings to disable all actin on lid close.
3. After a while, I observed that the SSH connection is slowing down after I leave the connection idle for some time. After some research, I tried changing the global `ServerAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveInterval` on both the Client and Server machines. This is supposed to keep the connection alive by sending out dummy packets.
4. Now again, after some idle time, the ssh connection is getting disconnected. I am neither able to connect via IP address or by hostname until I restart both the machines.

I began to doubt if I am on the right path. I am no expert in networking if that is not obvious from my experiences listed out above ;).

Should I go for a Ubuntu server version instead? I am not at all intending to use the GUI part at all. But the Ubuntu server installation seems to be a bit tough. Especially establishing network during installation.

Please advise me on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure that you disabled all power saving features on your laptop?  Any suspend on the system will cause your SSH to stop working for the time being until it wakes back up, which also means that you should disable the lid switch on the laptop.  Also, you should only need the `ServerAliveInterval` from the client side.

Comment: Will give a try